# Is there any way to use Flash in an HTML-based mobile app?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, cordova, phonegap-plugins

We're trying to combine HTML and Flash in a packaged mobile app. It needs to work on Android and it would be nice if it worked on iOS as well. One option is to use AIR with an SWF root containing a StageWebView, which should work, but we'd prefer to have the root of the app be in HTML and loading the SWF content as needed. Is there a way to do this by, for example, using Phonegap/Cordova or similar, perhaps with a plugin?

Comment: What is the role of the swf in your app? Does it perform code? Or is it only animation?

Comment: IMO there's no point. Rewrite your swf for AIR and make an app for all platforms with it..

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible. There's no plugin support for IOS.

The android situation only is slightly better since Adobe stopped publishing the plugin after/with Android 4.2. Older devices that have the plugin installed would work, the rest wouldn't. Also Adobes usage terms for the plugin wouldn't allow you to bundle it with your application if they didn't completely changed it since I checked it some years ago.

There are some solutions that might be providing you with what you look for some day, but they are not ready yet IMHO. Still, here some links:

- https://github.com/mozilla/shumway SWF-Player implemented in Javascript
- https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/ Flash content to HTML5 converter

That means right now Air is your only serious option if you want to combine Flash and HTML on the same mobile device.

*If you are still in the planning phase of your project or willing to rework the code* you could also evaluate Haxe/OpenFL which is **NOT FLASH** but would allows you to develope your application with the Haxe language (similar to AS3), work with a Flash like display model - and then export the project as HTML5, SWF (also Air) or native Mobile applications for IOS/Android:

- http://www.openfl.org/
- http://haxe.org/

Comment: It is possible, but with a lot of limitations. Especially when talking about Android.

Comment: @Andrey: Yes, it's possible on a limited number of devices with outdated Android versions. I mentioned it myself as you can see above. But the requirement was "It needs to work on Android" which I would interprete as "it needs to work on most android devices" which simply is not the case. Nobody sane would start to work on a mobile flash plugin based app these days.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have HTML as a root, it means that you will run Flash Player as a plugin. Since 2012, Adobe stopped supporting Flash Player for mobile. Which means that it can be done easily - as just embedding your swf into HTML page, **BUT** it won't run on almost any device. That's because the player **must** be installed as a plugin for the browser. What you want is to embed the swf just like you're doing it on your desktop, and pray that the browser has it installed and run it. Nowadays most of the devices do not support it.

There isn't any easy workaround, because of the fact that Adobe cut the rope. And it's the proper way that should be done, as that Flash would be a part of an HTML. It won't have access to any hardware nor it would have permissions for writing and things like that.

So if you want Flash inside mobile, it's almost certain that it must be within AIR - it's native wrapper.

And the short answer basically is - yes, just embed it as swf inside HTML, but it won't work on much devices :)

Answer (score 1):

I want to warn you that mobile webView has a lot of issues and limitations. As for me it is extremely bad idea to put flash player inside mobile webView (it looks like  the castle in the swamp). 
AIR as root application is definitely better solution (but anyway StageWebView brings a lot of pain too, it is just wrapper around native webView afaik).

Well, but if your choise is HTML, try to patch cordova\phonegap template (find there CordovaActivity class) to enable flash content as following:

```
WebSettings settings = appView.getSettings();
settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

Comment: I can see that would enable plugins. but does the Flash plugin need to be installed on the device already or does Cordova bundle it with the app? It's my understanding that Flash is no longer supported by the Android browser.

Comment: @JesseCrossen Did you find solution to this problem? I know its a long time ago but it might help me.

Comment: @MuhammadMehdiRaza The solution we chose at the time was to run the app in AIR and use a webview to show the HTML content, as was suggested by Eric above. Communication between the app and the webview is somewhat complex but doable using `javascript://` URIs to send data from AIR to HTML and by listening for changes to the webview's location to get data from HTML to AIR. Based on Adobe's seemingly halfhearted support of the technology however, I do not recommend basing a new project on Flash if you have other options.